# How to find the application responsible for a Share menu item?

Tags: share-menu

I have a duplicate "Copy" item in the "Share" menu when sharing a link from Firefox:

[image: Share menu screenshot]

The legitimate one is "Копировать", bottom left. The one that puzzles me is "Copy", second from the left in the top row.

How do I find which application is responsible for the "Copy" so I can remove it?

I have tried to share using the (fake?) "Copy" item. I get a toast notification saying "Не удалось отправить в это приложение" (Cannot send to this application) and the URL isn't copied.

Translations:

- Недавно использованные - recently used
- Все действия - all actions

This is Samsung Galaxy S8, Android 9, One UI 1.0.

Comment: That must be a [ShareActionProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider). Use `dumpsys package resolvers activity` to find apps which handle `android.intent.action.SEND` and `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sharedr](https://sharedr.rejh.nl/) ([Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rejh.sharedr)), a replacement share dialog app, can display this information:

- Install Sharedr.
- Launch the Share action.
- Choose "Sharedr" instead of default Android share (you can choose "Just once" if you don't want to keep using Sharedr).
- In the action list, long press an item and choose "App Info". It will take you to the responsible application's settings.

P.S. Fake "Copy" menu item is [AfterShip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aftership.AfterShip).